# Insert array values in table cell with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to insert some values ​​in a table. All values are contained in a returned array from an Ajax/php request like this:

```
var data = [];

//Consider that the number of the object (in this case only 3) obtained from the server are equal to the number of rows in tbody (6 rows in tbody = 6 object from server).

data[0] = {From: '01/01/2012', To: '01/01/2013', Interest: 80.00, Residual: 0, Capital: 1000.00, Days: 366};
data[1] = {From: '01/01/2013', To: '01/01/2014', Interest: 85.00, Residual: 0, Capital: 980.00, Days: 365};
data[2] = {From: '01/01/2014', To: '29/04/2014', Interest: 20.00, Residual: 75.00, Capital: 980.00, Days: 118};
```

It's a bit tricky to explain how the values must to be inserted in the table, so I created a fiddle with the result I would like to get.
I do not expect you to give me the final result (of course, would be welcome :) ), but at least some idea from which to start.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nb3gr/1/)**

****EDIT**

I assigned id to cells and now all values are right inserted. That's the updated fiddle, do you think code can be written more elegantly?

**[UPDATE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nb3gr/3/)**

Comment: start with assigning respective id's to cells if that is in your control. Do the required calculation and fill the respective cells.

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I can see the data returned from ajax/php request is in JSON format. So to insert them in HTML table you can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Example (as you given sample data):

```
function buildDataTableHtml(data){
    var tableHtml = "<table><tr>";
    tableHtml += "<th>From</th>";
    tableHtml += "<th>To</th>";
    tableHtml += "<th>Interest</th>";
    tableHtml += "<th>Residual</th>";
    tableHtml += "<th>Capital</th>";
    tableHtml += "<th>Days</th>";
    tableHtml += "</tr>";

    $.each(data, function(i, v){
        tableHtml += "<tr>";
        tableHtml += "<td>" + v.From + "</td>";
        tableHtml += "<td>" + v.To + "</td>";
        tableHtml += "<td>" + v.Interest + "</td>";
        tableHtml += "<td>" + v.Residual + "</td>";
        tableHtml += "<td>" + v.Capital + "</td>";
        tableHtml += "<td>" + v.Days + "</td>";
        tableHtml += "</tr>";
    });
    tableHtml += "</table>";

    return tableHtml;
}
```

If you use this JavaScript function (along with JQuery) then this function will return the HTML of a table you wanted. Hope this will be helpful for you

NOTE: I just write it down in answer box, didn't try to make sure this is working. But hope the code will work. :)